# Looping things in Mathematica

Tags: infinite-loop, procedural-programming

So let me start by stating I'm really new to *Mathematica*.
Being a biologist..
I'm trying to make two different loops.
And I've been googling around and looking at some youtube video.
But, I'm getting a bit stressed out so;

I'm trying to make a sine loop and a "special" sine function---where the later one is a big struggle in how to implement it to *Mathematica*.

For the sine loop my logical thought is;

`t==0; while  t< Ssk1 do t+0.0001; if t>Skk1 stop; then do t-0.0001; until t==0;   then do t+0.0001; where Ssk1==0.02675`

I would get a sinus loop, right?

The purpose of the special function is to have a break. Where nothing happens.
So here my thinking is;

`t==0.00001;

while  t<Ssk1 do t+0.00001; if t>=0 then do nothing for 300; then do t+0.00001`.

My issue is putting it in *Mathematica* language. I just can't. I think some simple examples of reasoning will get me going.

And I do apologies if this is a bad or stupid question. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your question is not stupid, but it is a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: Triangle wave actually. Try the following. `ssk1 = 0.02675;
up1 = Table[t, {t, 0, ssk1, .0001}];
down1 = Table[t, {t, ssk1, 0, -.0001}];
up2 = Table[t, {t, 0, ssk1, .0001}];
down2 = Table[t, {t, ssk1, 0, -.0001}];
ListPlot[Join[up1, down1, up2, down2]]`. There are better ways to code this but I wanted to make it as close to your pseudocode as possible, so it would be easier to follow.

Answer (score 5):

As alluded to by Daniel Lichtblau you could use `TriangleWave` with appropriate scaling, e.g.

```
amp = 0.02675;
per = 4 amp/0.0001;
DiscretePlot[Abs@TriangleWave[{-amp, amp}, x/per], {x, 0, 2 per, 1}, 
 Filling -> None]
```

[image]

Compared with  @DanielLichtblau comment code:

```
ssk1 = 0.02675; up1 = Table[t, {t, 0, ssk1, .0001}]; down1 = 
 Table[t, {t, ssk1, 0, -.0001}]; up2 = 
 Table[t, {t, 0, ssk1, .0001}]; down2 = 
 Table[t, {t, ssk1, 0, -.0001}]; Show[
 ListPlot[Join[up1, down1, up2, down2]], 
 DiscretePlot[Abs@TriangleWave[{-amp, amp}, x/per], {x, 0, 500, 1}, 
  Filling -> None, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]

Or you could code a switch when event of interest arises, e.g.

```
fun[n_] := 
 Module[{s = 1}, 
  NestList[(If[# > 0.02675 || # < 0, s = -s]; #1 + s 0.0001`) &, 
   0.0001, n]]
```

e.g.

```
Show[ListPlot[fun[3000]], 
 DiscretePlot[Abs@TriangleWave[{-amp, amp}, x/per], {x, 0, 2000, 1}, 
  Filling -> None, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]

There are some numerical issues around turning points:

```
fun[540][[-10 ;; -1]]
fun[270][[-10 ;; -1]]
```

yield:

> {0.0004, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0001, 2.43945*10^-19, -0.0001, 
>    2.43945*10^-19, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003}
>    and
>
> {0.0262, 0.0263, 0.0264, 0.0265, 0.0266, 0.0267, 0.0268, 0.0267, \
>   0.0266, 0.0265}

respectively